# Counting Words in Files - MATLAB style

Tags: performance, strings, homework, matlab

For my Matlab class I'm taking, I was given the task to write a function `ReadAndCountWords` that takes in the name of a text file (specifically from [this zip file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rrcfcdqfacin4g8/Speeches.zip?dl=0)) as an input argument and then prints out the words contained in that file in order of how many times the word occurs. The function doesn't have to produce any output through output arguments. A call to the function might produce a result like this:

```
>> ReadAndCountWords('Speeches/Abraham_Lincoln_The_Gettysburg_Address.txt');
All words:
word: that                  count:  13
word: the                   count:  11
word: we                    count:  10
word: here                  count:   8
word: to                    count:   8
word: a                     count:   7
word: and                   count:   6
word: for                   count:   5
word: have                  count:   5
word: it                    count:   5
word: nation                count:   5
word: of                    count:   5
word: dedicated             count:   4
word: in                    count:   4
word: this                  count:   4
word: are                   count:   3
word: cannot                count:   3
word: dead                  count:   3
word: great                 count:   3
word: is                    count:   3
word: people                count:   3
word: shall                 count:   3
word: so                    count:   3
word: they                  count:   3
word: us                    count:   3
word: who                   count:   3
word: be                    count:   2
word: but                   count:   2
word: can                   count:   2
word: conceived             count:   2
word: dedicate              count:   2
word: devotion              count:   2
word: far                   count:   2
word: from                  count:   2
word: gave                  count:   2
word: living                count:   2
word: long                  count:   2
word: men                   count:   2
word: new                   count:   2
word: not                   count:   2
word: on                    count:   2
word: or                    count:   2
word: our                   count:   2
word: rather                count:   2
word: these                 count:   2
word: war                   count:   2
word: what                  count:   2
word: which                 count:   2
word: above                 count:   1
word: add                   count:   1
word: advanced              count:   1
word: ago                   count:   1
word: all                   count:   1
word: altogether            count:   1
word: any                   count:   1
word: as                    count:   1
word: battlefield           count:   1
word: before                count:   1
word: birth                 count:   1
word: brave                 count:   1
word: brought               count:   1
word: by                    count:   1
word: cause                 count:   1
word: civil                 count:   1
word: come                  count:   1
word: consecrate            count:   1
word: consecrated           count:   1
word: continent             count:   1
word: created               count:   1
word: detract               count:   1
word: did                   count:   1
word: died                  count:   1
word: do                    count:   1
word: earth                 count:   1
word: endure                count:   1
word: engaged               count:   1
word: equal                 count:   1
word: fathers               count:   1
word: field                 count:   1
word: final                 count:   1
word: fitting               count:   1
word: forget                count:   1
word: forth                 count:   1
word: fought                count:   1
word: four                  count:   1
word: freedom               count:   1
word: full                  count:   1
word: god                   count:   1
word: government            count:   1
word: ground                count:   1
word: hallow                count:   1
word: highly                count:   1
word: honored               count:   1
word: increased             count:   1
word: larger                count:   1
word: last                  count:   1
word: liberty               count:   1
word: little                count:   1
word: live                  count:   1
word: lives                 count:   1
word: measure               count:   1
word: met                   count:   1
word: might                 count:   1
word: never                 count:   1
word: nobly                 count:   1
word: nor                   count:   1
word: note                  count:   1
word: now                   count:   1
word: perish                count:   1
word: place                 count:   1
word: poor                  count:   1
word: portion               count:   1
word: power                 count:   1
word: proper                count:   1
word: proposition           count:   1
word: remaining             count:   1
word: remember              count:   1
word: resolve               count:   1
word: resting               count:   1
word: say                   count:   1
word: score                 count:   1
word: sense                 count:   1
word: seven                 count:   1
word: should                count:   1
word: struggled             count:   1
word: take                  count:   1
word: task                  count:   1
word: testing               count:   1
word: their                 count:   1
word: those                 count:   1
word: thus                  count:   1
word: under                 count:   1
word: unfinished            count:   1
word: vain                  count:   1
word: whether               count:   1
word: will                  count:   1
word: work                  count:   1
word: world                 count:   1
word: years                 count:   1
```

Some guidelines I was given:

> - The code should drop all punctuation, except for `'` (contraction)    marks. For example, "don't" should be considered one word.
> - Once the code has divided things into words, it should eliminate `'` marks    (contractions) from the interior of words (so "don't"
>     should be    listed as "dont").
> - All words should be converted to lower case.
> - A word is considered to match only if it is a precise match using the    `strcmp` routine ("discovered" and "discover" are different
>     words).
> - Searching for a word in a cell array can be useful.
> - The code will need to print out the words ordered by the number of    occurrences from most to least. Those words that have the same number 
>     of occurrences should be sorted alphabetically. So, if two words both 
>     occur 2 times, the word that is earlier alphabetically should occur
>     first in the listed output.

And for extra credit:

> The `Speeches` folder contains one more file: `stop_words.txt`. In text
>   processing, it is often considered useful to eliminate words that we
>   expect to occur with extremely high frequency because they are filler
>   words (and carry little to no actual information). For example, the
>   words "a", "the" and "this" occur with high frequency and carry no
>   useful information about the file itself because virtually all files
>   will contain many of these words. Such words are often referred to as
>   stop words. The file `stop_words.txt` contains an example of such a list
>   of words.
>
> For extra credit, add a process to your code that reads in the set of
>   stop words, and when you print out the words that occur in a speech,
>   you should exclude all stop words.
>
> **Note:**
>
> You must be able to call your code both ways:
>
> - Showing the results as indicated in the project write-up above
> - And showing the results with stop words excluded

Example output for extra credit:

```
Without stop words:
word: nation                count:   5
word: dedicated             count:   4
word: dead                  count:   3
word: great                 count:   3
word: people                count:   3
word: shall                 count:   3
word: conceived             count:   2
word: dedicate              count:   2
word: devotion              count:   2
word: far                   count:   2
word: gave                  count:   2
word: living                count:   2
word: long                  count:   2
word: men                   count:   2
word: new                   count:   2
word: war                   count:   2
word: add                   count:   1
word: advanced              count:   1
word: ago                   count:   1
word: altogether            count:   1
word: battlefield           count:   1
word: birth                 count:   1
word: brave                 count:   1
word: brought               count:   1
word: cause                 count:   1
word: civil                 count:   1
word: come                  count:   1
word: consecrate            count:   1
word: consecrated           count:   1
word: continent             count:   1
word: created               count:   1
word: detract               count:   1
word: did                   count:   1
word: died                  count:   1
word: earth                 count:   1
word: endure                count:   1
word: engaged               count:   1
word: equal                 count:   1
word: fathers               count:   1
word: field                 count:   1
word: final                 count:   1
word: fitting               count:   1
word: forget                count:   1
word: forth                 count:   1
word: fought                count:   1
word: freedom               count:   1
word: god                   count:   1
word: government            count:   1
word: ground                count:   1
word: hallow                count:   1
word: highly                count:   1
word: honored               count:   1
word: increased             count:   1
word: larger                count:   1
word: liberty               count:   1
word: little                count:   1
word: live                  count:   1
word: lives                 count:   1
word: measure               count:   1
word: met                   count:   1
word: nobly                 count:   1
word: note                  count:   1
word: perish                count:   1
word: place                 count:   1
word: poor                  count:   1
word: portion               count:   1
word: power                 count:   1
word: proper                count:   1
word: proposition           count:   1
word: remaining             count:   1
word: remember              count:   1
word: resolve               count:   1
word: resting               count:   1
word: say                   count:   1
word: score                 count:   1
word: sense                 count:   1
word: seven                 count:   1
word: struggled             count:   1
word: task                  count:   1
word: testing               count:   1
word: unfinished            count:   1
word: vain                  count:   1
word: work                  count:   1
word: world                 count:   1
word: years                 count:   1
```

---

My implementation (what I'm looking to have reviewed):

**`ReadAndCountWords.m`**:

```
function ReadAndCountWords(fileName, stopFile)
if (exist('stopFile', 'var')) 
    stopid = fopen(stopFile);
    stopData = textscan(stopid, '%s');
    stopData = lower(stopData{1});
else
    stopData = [];
end
fileid = fopen(fileName);
data = textscan(fileid, '%s');

data = regexprep(lower(data{1}), '[^a-z]', '');
[words, ~, labels] = unique(data);
count = histc(labels, 1:max(labels));

[count, indices] = sort(count, 'descend');
words = words(indices);
if (isempty(stopData))
    fprintf('All words:\n');
else
    fprintf('Without stop words:\n');
end
for i = 1:length(count)
    if(~isempty(words{i}) && ~any(strcmp(stopData, words{i})))
        fprintf('word: %-20s count %5d\n', words{i}, count(i));
    end
end

fclose('all');
end
```

And the driver (don't review this please):

**`Word_Count_Speeches.m`**:

```
diaryFile = 'project3Results.txt';

if exist(diaryFile)
  delete(diaryFile);
end

% Count for all speeches
diary(diaryFile);

fileName = 'Speeches/Abraham_Lincoln_The_Gettysburg_Address.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

fileName = 'Speeches/Abraham_Lincoln_First_Inaugural.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

fileName = 'Speeches/Abraham_Lincoln_Second_Inaugural.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

fileName = 'Speeches/Franklin_Delano_Roosevelt_First_Inaugural.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

fileName = 'Speeches/Franklin_Delano_Roosevelt_Pearl_Harbor_Address.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

fileName = 'Speeches/John_F_Kennedy_Inaugural.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

fileName = 'Speeches/Malcolm_X_The_Ballot_Or_The_Bullet.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

fileName = 'Speeches/Martin_Luther_King_I_Have_A_Dream.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

fileName = 'Speeches/Susan_B_Anthony_On_Women_s_Right_To_Vote.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

fileName = 'Speeches/Theodore_Roosevelt_The_Duties_Of_American_Citizenship.txt';
fprintf('For file %s:\n',fileName);
ReadAndCountWords(fileName);

diary off;

clear diaryFile fileName;
```

Running my code with `tic; Word_Count_Speeches; toc;`, my code ran in 3.047776 seconds.

Are there ways that I can clean up my function more?  Are there ways I can get rid of those `for` loops I have and use vectorization instead?  Can I speed up my code to make it more efficient?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than going through all of `labels` looking for the biggest in this line:

```
count = histc(labels, 1:max(labels))
```

you can pick this number off directly with `numel(labels)`:

```
count = histc(labels, 1:numel(labels))
```

Alternatively, you can use `accumarray`:

```
count = accumarray(labels,1);
```

---

On this line in the loop

```
if(~isempty(words{i}) && ~any(strcmp(stopData, words{i})))
```

scanning through the stopData list on every iteration is expensive. Instead, you could use `intersect` to filter out the stopData before this print loop.

---

Rather than `exist` to see if a variable has been passed in,

```
if (exist('stopFile', 'var'))
```

I prefer to use `nargin`.

```
if (nargin < 2)
```